# How to copy one file to a specific subdirectory in all application data directories in C:\Users?

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, copy

One Windows 7 x64 I am trying to copy one file to

```
C:\users\profilename\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\R18.1\enu\Plotters
```

I would like the batch to copy this file to all user profiles that exist on the client PC silently with no prompts.

The code I have tried so far with no luck:

```
@echo off
xcopy /I /Y "%~dp0myfile.pc3" "C:\Users\*\Appdata\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\R18.1\enu\Plotters"
```

Any ideas on how to do this with a batch file?

Comment: Thank You Mofi for your explanation and code. I tested it out and it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards can't be used inside a folder path. The Windows command interpreter does support that.

You could use the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "TargetPath=AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\R18.1\enu\Plotters"

rem Get path of folder containing the users' profile folders.
for /F %%I in ("%PUBLIC%") do set "UsersFolder=%%~dpI"

rem Copy file into a subdirectory of each non standard user profile folder.
for /D %%I in (%UsersFolder%*) do (
    if /I not "%%I" == "%PUBLIC%" (
        if /I not "%%~nxI" == "Default" (
            if not exist "%%I\%TargetPath%\*" md "%%I\%TargetPath%"
            copy /B /Y "%~dp0myfile.pc3" "%%I\%TargetPath%\" >nul
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

The subfolders `Default` and `Public` are skipped by this batch code.

This batch file must be of course run as administrator as otherwise the file can be only copied to `%APPDATA%\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2011\R18.1\enu\Plotters`, i.e. the appropriate subdirectory in the application data directory of AutoCAD 2011 of the current user account.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`